# How avoid SQL Injection without stored procedure In C# Desktop Application

Tags: c#, sql

I am developing C# desktop appllication using MS SQL server database.
I Keep different class as follow connect to database.

```
 using System.Data.Odbc;

class DataBaseConnection
    {
        private OdbcConnection conn1 = new OdbcConnection(@"FILEDSN=C:/OTPub/Ot.dsn;" + "Uid=sa;" + "Pwd=otdata@123;"); //"DSN=Ot_DataODBC;" + "Uid=sa;" +  "Pwd=otdata@123;"

        //insert,update,delete
        public int SetData(string query)
        {
            try
            {
                conn1.Open();
                OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(query, conn1);
                int rs = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn1.Close();
                return rs;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                conn1.Close();
                throw ex;
            }
        }
        //select
        public System.Data.DataTable GetData(string sql)
        {
            try
            {
                conn1.Open();
                OdbcDataAdapter adpt = new OdbcDataAdapter(sql, conn1);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                adpt.Fill(dt);
                conn1.Close();
                return dt;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                conn1.Close();
                throw ex;
            }
        }

   }
```

in my reqierd place i make object to that **DatabaseConnection** class and call to get and set method as requirment.

as an example ----

```
 DataBaseConnection db = new DataBaseConnection();

 string SaveNewEmp = "INSERT INTO Employee  (Service_ID, Title, Name, Initials, ) VALUES ('" + servicenumber + "','" + title + "','" + fullname + "','" + initials + "')";
                    int returns = db.SetData(SaveNewEmp);
```

- am i allow to SQl injection from this method?
- how avoid sql injection without using  stored procedure?

Comment: Yes it is very easy to do SQL Injection on your query above. 1 answer. Parameters parameters parameters. [Parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements) & this goes side by side this days [Using Add instead of AddWithValue](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx

Comment: Why using Odbc insted of Sql .Net driver (e.g. SqlConnection)? Use parametrized queries as @P.Pat and Damien_The_Unbeliever mention. Why don't you use some ORM?

Comment: But, how i use parameters inside  "DataBaseConnection Class"  ? i used this class get and set data all-over my program,through this class parse more than   150 different quary  to the data base?how am i customize parameters according to that different quary? any one can help? @P.Pat

Comment: @GayanChinthakaDharmarathna What I can suggest is that you learn stored procedures and see if you can implement it in your current DBMS. It also prevents sql injection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most important technique is to used bind variables like this:

```
 string SaveNewEmp = 
   "INSERT INTO Employee  (Service_ID, Title, Name, Initials) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

command.Parameters.Add("@servicenumber", OdbcType.Int).Value = ...;
command.Parameters.Add("@title", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = ...;
command.Parameters.Add("@fullname ", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = ...;
command.Parameters.Add("@initials ", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = ...;
```

Usually this lead also into a performance gain and you don't have to take care about quoting, imagine the `title` would be `It's your day` - this would fail with your approach.

**Update**

Using a list of parameters is straight forward:

```
public int SetData(string query, OdbcParameterCollection parList)
{
   ...  
   OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(query, conn1);
   OdbcCommand.Parameters.Add(parList);
}


var parList = new OdbcParameterCollection();
parList.Add("@servicenumber", OdbcType.Int);
parList.Add("@title", OdbcType.VarChar);
...
int ret = SetData(query, parList);
```

However, I did not test it perhaps you have to run

```
foreach ( OdbcParameter aPar in parList ) { 
    OdbcCommand.Parameters.Add(aPar);
}
```

Using `List<>`

Comment: But, how i use parameters inside "DataBaseConnection Class" ? i used this class get and set data all-over my program,through this class parse more than 150 different quary to the data base?how am i customize parameters according to that different quary?

Comment: You can prepare an array (or `List(T)`, etc.) of Parameters outside and pass this array as an argument to DataBaseConnection constructor. Then allocate parameters in a loop.

Comment: can you suggest me a example for use of array or List(T)?

Answer (score 9):

You avoid SQL Injection the same way as you would anywhere else - by keeping SQL *code* separate from *data*. You can't do that if you insist on having the interface be based on just passing in a string.

I'd get rid of your wrapper class (it's just obscuring things) and make use of [Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcparameter(v=vs.110).aspx) to pass the data alongside your query.

---

(I'd also recommend that you just use `using` statements around the various database objects rather than your current manual efforts to ensure `Close` is called which is also slightly breaking good error handling by re-throwing exceptions)

(Also, I'd recommend using new `OdbcConnection` objects wherever you need them rather than trying to share a single one - you'll be thankful you've done this as soon as any notion of multi-threading enters your codebase, which is practically inevitable these days)

Answer (score 1):

Damien_The_Unbeliever's answer is mostly good, but I would like to improve it/ version it.

You can also change the `SetData` and `GetData` methods and add them an array of parameters (although I do share his/her thoughts in getting rid of the class, you could make it abstract to make more specifica DAL classes).

The only requirement to avoid SQL Injection is using parameters, either using stored procedures (impossible due to question requirements) or queries written in your code.

There is a slight chance of getting into SQL Injection even if using parameters, if the SQL executed (in coded query or in the stored procedure) does use `sp_execute_sql` or similar. In case of using `sp_execute_sql` in your query, make sure to avoid writting it with user provided info. You can set parameters to the sp_execute_sql function as a second optional parameter.

Answer (score 1):

This is a recurring (for the last 20 years at least) question, but I earnestly believe I have a new answer... use QueryFirst. You get the advantages of stored procedures, but your SQL lives in .sql files in your application, versioned with your app. You create parameters just by referencing them in your SQL. All the parameter handling code is generated for you. You (and your team) have to use parameters because there's no other way. The possibility of doing something unsafe is removed. And there are tons of other advantages: you edit your sql in a real environment, with syntax validation and intellisense. Your queries are continually integration tested against your db, and their wrapper code regenerated. All errors are trapped as you type, or when you save a .sql, or, last resort, when you build. In theory, there  are no runtime errors from data access.

Usually rigour comes at the cost of simplicity/ease-of-dev. This approach is *much more rigorous and much easier to use* than the traditional sql-in-string-literals approach. Coming soon, language and platform portability. Drag and drop a sql query from C# project on windows into a Node express app on linux or mac, rebuild, and you get a typescript wrapper instead of a C# one. That should get folk's attention.

disclaimer: I wrote QueryFirst.
Download [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bbsimonbb.QueryFirst).
Little blog [here](http://geniusorfantasist.blogspot.fr/).